# autoconf recipe to use gcc-ar and gcc-ranlib

Tags: gcc, autoconf, automake, lto

I'm using link-time optimisation (LTO) in a [project](https://github.com/ska-sa/spead2) that compiles under both GCC and Clang and builds a static library. It's working with GCC 4.8, but GCC 5.4 makes thin LTO objects and when automake tries to build the static library with `ar` it fails, because it needs the wrapper script `gcc-ar`.

Is there a good example I can look at for how to make automake use `gcc-ar` instead of `ar` (and similarly for `gcc-ranlib`)? I can probably hack something in, but ideally it should:

- Use the appropriate tools for the compiler (Clang has its [own instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html)).
- Work even if the user overrides the compiler to one that isn't the system default.
- Work when cross compiling

Answer (score 3):

You can override the default tools used by calling

```
./configure AR=gcc-ar RANLIB=gcc-ranlib
```

I'm afraid for `./configure` to pick them up by default, autoconf/automake will have to be fixed to know about those in the default set of checks.

Comment: One can write a custom set of checks to do this (autoconf is fully extensible). My question is whether any project has already done this so that I can follow their example, rather than figure out how to handle all the compilers on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```sh
AC_ARG_VAR([AR], [AR command (default is gcc-ar)])
AC_CHECK_TOOL([AR], [gcc-ar])

AC_ARG_VAR([RANLIB], [RANLIB command (default is gcc-ranlib)])
AC_CHECK_TOOL([RANLIB], [gcc-ranlib])
```

- `AC_ARG_VAR` is there just to document it, when invoking `./configure --help`.
- `AC_CHECK_TOOL` is used for these tools, instead of `AC_CHECK_PROGS`, so the right version is used when cross-compiling.
- You can still override `AR`, `RANLIB` when invoking `./configure`.
- To fallback to regular `ar` and regular `ranlib`, you can use `AC_CHECK_TOOLS` instead:

  ```
  AC_CHECK_TOOLS([AR], [gcc-ar ar])
  ```
- An optional third argument can be set to something like `:` so you can test if none of the tools were found:

  ```
  AC_CHECK_TOOLS([AR], [gcc-ar ar], [:])
  AS_VAR_IF([AR], [:], AC_MSG_ERROR([could not find AR tool.]))
  ```

---

For Clang, they follow a different naming convention: `llvm-ar`, `llvm-ranlib`, `llvm-objcopy`, etc. I'll be using two helper macros.

First, we define `MY_CHECK_TOOL_PREFIX`, using [AX_COMPILER_VENDOR](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compiler_vendor.html), this will try to guess what tool prefix to use; it can be overridden with the `TOOL_PREFIX` variable. It will test the compiler for the current language (defaults to C); make sure to call `AC_LANG(C++)` beforehand if needed. It's used by the next macro, you don't need to call it manually.

```
AC_DEFUN([MY_CHECK_TOOL_PREFIX],
[
    AC_REQUIRE([AX_COMPILER_VENDOR])
    AC_ARG_VAR([TOOL_PREFIX], [tool prefix (gcc, llvm)])
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([toolchain prefix])
    # only convert vendor to prefix if not already set
    AS_VAR_SET_IF([TOOL_PREFIX],
        [],
        [
            AS_CASE([${ax_cv_[]_AC_LANG_ABBREV[]_compiler_vendor}],
                [gnu], [TOOL_PREFIX="gcc"],
                [clang], [TOOL_PREFIX="llvm"],
                [TOOL_PREFIX="unknown"])
        ])
    AC_MSG_RESULT([$TOOL_PREFIX])
])
```

Then comes the macro you'll be using: `MY_CHECK_TOOL`. The default action, if not variant of the tool is found, is to abort.

```
dnl MY_CHECK_TOOL(TOOL, PROGRAM-TO-CHECK, [ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND])
AC_DEFUN([MY_CHECK_TOOL],
[
    AC_REQUIRE([MY_CHECK_TOOL_PREFIX])
    AC_ARG_VAR($1, [$1 command (default is TOOL_PREFIX-$2, $2)])
    AC_CHECK_TOOLS($1, [${TOOL_PREFIX}-$2 $2], [:])
    AS_VAR_IF($1, [:],
        [m4_ifblank($3,
            [AC_MSG_ERROR([could not find $1])],
            $3)])
])
```

You can save both in a `my_prefix_tools.m4` file in your M4 dir, if you don't want to clutter your `configure.ac`.

And here's how you'd use it in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG(C++)
MY_CHECK_TOOL([AR], [ar])
MY_CHECK_TOOL([RANLIB], [ranlib])
MY_CHECK_TOOL([OBJCOPY], [objcopy])
MY_CHECK_TOOL([NM], [nm])
```

When running `./configure` where g++ is the default C++ compiler, this is the output:

```
checking for C++ compiler vendor... gnu
checking toolchain prefix... gcc
checking for gcc-ar... gcc-ar
checking for gcc-ranlib... gcc-ranlib
checking for gcc-objcopy... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for gcc-nm... gcc-nm
```

And when running `./configure CXX=clang++`, this is the output:

```
checking for C++ compiler vendor... clang
checking toolchain prefix... llvm
checking for llvm-ar... llvm-ar
checking for llvm-ranlib... llvm-ranlib
checking for llvm-objcopy... llvm-objcopy
checking for llvm-nm... llvm-nm
```

Comment: Will that automatically handle Clang though, without the user needing to override anything other than CXX=clang++?

Comment: I turned it into macros, for more convenient usage.